# Proving $f,g \in \mathbb D(U)$ (differentiable on $U$) $\implies f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable on U and $(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

This is done using compisition :

$$x \mapsto^{F}(f(x),g(x))\mapsto^{B}f(x)g(x) \\
    P(x)=B \circ F(x) \implies P'(x)h=B'(F(x))F'(x)h....(1)\\
\text{ I know that $B'(x)=B({}^1,\beta)+B(\alpha, {}^2)$ because it is a bilinear function. I also know that   $F'(x)=(f'(x), g'(x))$ but in my notebook it uses this to get the following which I do not see how:} \\ ...(1)(B({}^1,\beta)+B(\alpha, {}^2))(f'(x)h , g'(x)h)=f'(x)hg(x)+g'(x)hf(x)=... \\ \text{ this is obvious from previous: }...=(f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x))h. $$

Comment: Is $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) and are $f,g$ scalar valued? Any way $\alpha = f(x)$ and $\beta = g(x)$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Could you type it out, I just dont see it, but I am aware of what you state. Also  $\mathbb R$

Comment: Notice $B'(\alpha,\beta)$ is itself a linear mapping given by $B'(\alpha,\beta)[\delta\alpha, \delta\beta] = B(\delta\alpha, \beta) + B(\alpha, \delta\beta)$. Now, by chain rule you have $P'(x)h = B'(F(x)) [F'(x)h]$, where $F(x) = (f(x), g(x)) = (\alpha,\beta)$ and $F'(x)h = (f'(x)h, g'(x)h) = (\delta\alpha, \delta\beta)$. That is $P'(x)h = B'(F(x)) [F'(x)h] = B'(f(x), g(x))[f'(x)h, g(x)h] = B(f'(x)h, g(x)) + B(f(x), g'(x)h) = f'(x)hg(x) + f(x)g'(x)h$.

Comment: Just copy this as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $B'(\alpha,\beta)$ is itself a linear mapping given by $$B'(\alpha,\beta)[\delta\alpha, \delta\beta]=B(\delta\alpha, \beta)+B(\alpha, \delta\beta).$$ 
Now, by chain rule you have $P'(x)h=B'(F(x))[F'(x)h]$, where $F(x)=(f(x),g(x))=(\alpha, \beta)$ and $F'(x)h=(f'(x)h, g'(x)h)=(\delta\alpha, \delta\beta)$. That is 
\begin{align} 
P'(x)h &= B'(F(x))[F'(x)h] \\
&=B'(f(x),g(x))[f'(x)h,g(x)h] \\
&=B(f'(x)h,g(x))+B(f(x),g'(x)h) \\
&=f'(x)hg(x)+f(x)g'(x)h.
\end{align}